# Calling a sub to another worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have a sub that goes through each worksheet and checks for a flag.

If the flag is raised, I want it to run another sub. The flag checking works, but the other sub which is called runs on the main sheet.

Code:

```
Sub update()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If (ws.Cells(1, 5) = 1) Then
            Call update2(ws)
        End If
    Next
End Sub


Sub update2(ws As Worksheet)
    ws.clear   <----does not work
End Sub


sub dothis() 
    cells(1,6) = "hallo"
end sub
```

how do I get this to work?

Comment: Object does not support this property or method. That error message is fairly unambiguous. THere is no `Clear` method on the Worksheet object. The `.Clear` method pertains to Range objects.

Comment: sub clear() might not be a good idea, clear is a keyword

Comment: @DavidZemens thanks. I changed the name, but still doesn't work

Comment: What do you mean you cahnged the name?

Comment: @Alex thanks, but still does not work

Comment: @DavidZemens I changed the sub name from clear to dothis because clear is a built in keyword. 

I want dothis sub to run on the flagged worksheet

Comment: @user1681664 What is not working?  Do you actually means you want to call the sub dothis() from the other sub update2()?

Comment: @Alex yes exactly and I want the sub dothis() to run on the flagged worksheet

Comment: There I think David provided you with an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to either use a public variable (generally not recommended) or send the necessary arguments to the procedure(s) where they are needed.

```
Sub update2(ws As Worksheet)
    Call dothis(ws)
End Sub


sub dothis(ws as Worksheet) 
    ws.cells(1,6) = "hallo"
end sub
```

Comment: I already tried this before, but this updates the activesheet and does not update the flagged sheet

I want the project to run through all the sheets and execute dothis() on every flagged sheet

Comment: No, you didn't try this before. Previously you tried `Cells(1,6) = "hallo"`. *That* will only affect the activesheet. But since you're assigning `ws` as `Each Worksheet`, in a loop, if you do `ws.Cells(1,6)` that should apply to *each* worksheet.

Comment: I did do it like that before this, but I was trying to do it in a shorter way. I guess there is no shortcut around this. thanks for your help though

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub update2(ws As Worksheet)
    ws.Cells.Clear
End Sub
```

Comment: sorry, I think I confused people. I want to run MY sub called clear. i'll change the name